# Trying to create a linking table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

```
CREATE TABLE patient 
(
    patientid INT NOT NULL,
    patientname VARCHAR(100),
    patientphone VARCHAR(100),

    CONSTRAINT PK_patient PRIMARY KEY (patientid)
)

CREATE TABLE doctor 
(
    doctorid INT NOT NULL,
    doctorname VARCHAR(100),

    CONSTRAINT PK_doctor PRIMARY KEY (doctorid)
)

CREATE TABLE drug 
(
    drugname VARCHAR(100),
    drugid INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_drug PRIMARY KEY (drugid)
)

CREATE TABLE visit  
(
    visitid INT NOT NULL,
    visitdate DATE,
    visitreason VARCHAR(200),
    doctorid INT REFERENCES doctor (doctorid),
    patientid INT REFERENCES patient (patientid),
    PRIMARY KEY (visitid, doctorid, patientid)
)

CREATE TABLE druglinkingtable 
(
    drugid INT REFERENCES drug (drugid),
    visitid INT REFERENCES visit (visitid),
    PRIMARY KEY (drugid, visitid)
)
```

Getting error in druglinkingtable:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'visit' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__druglinki__visit__44FF419A

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? You have defined a 3 part PK for `Visit`, `PRIMARY KEY(visitid,doctorid,patientid)` and are trying to reference it with a 1 part FK `visitid INT REFERENCES visit(visitid),`. I don't see any reason for a 3 part PK on `Visit` myself.

Comment: You probably just want `visitid` as primary key of `visit`? Or what else would be the purpose of that column?

Answer (score 1):

Any Foreign key referencing Visit must target a unique index.  You could use the compound PK you have or, make visitid the PK.

```
CREATE TABLE visit  
(
    visitid INT NOT NULL,
    visitdate DATE,
    visitreason VARCHAR(200),
    doctorid INT REFERENCES doctor (doctorid),
    patientid INT REFERENCES patient (patientid),
    CONSTRAINT pk_visit PRIMARY KEY (visitid),
    INDEX ix_doctorid (doctorId),
    INDEX ix_patientid (patientid)
)
```

The other reasonable design for visit is:

```
CREATE TABLE visit  
(
    visitid INT NOT NULL,
    visitdate DATE,
    visitreason VARCHAR(200),
    doctorid INT REFERENCES doctor (doctorid),
    patientid INT REFERENCES patient (patientid),
    CONSTRAINT pk_visit PRIMARY KEY (patientid,doctorid,visitid),
    INDEX ix_doctorid (doctorId)    
)
```

and then

```
CREATE TABLE druglinkingtable 
(
    patientid int,
    doctorid int 
    visitid INT REFERENCES visit (patientid,doctorid,visitid),
    drugid INT REFERENCES drug (drugid),
    PRIMARY KEY (patientid,doctorid,visitid,drugid),
    INDEX ix_drugid (drugid)
)
```